# how to restore mongodb data after my mongdb container has been removed

Tags: mongodb, docker

I run a `mongodb` in docker container, and i have data file backup.

But today I removed my `mongodb` careless.

I tried to run an another container and put the datafile into the container, but it did not work.

How can I restore my data from the data file?

the database file I only have now:
[image]

the container I use is tutum/mongodb.my docker-compose.yml file is

`mongo_db:
  image: tutum/mongodb
  privileged: true
  restart: always
  ports:
  - 27016:27017
  - 28016:28017
  volumes:
  - /var/mongodb:/data/db
  environment:
  - MONGODB_PASS=xxxxxx
  - AUTH=yes`

and now I want restore my data from dirctory /var/mongodb to my new container

I put the file except mongod.lock in my new container,but my mongodb can't run.
it's the screenshot:
[image]

the mongod.conf is:

```
# Where to store the data.

# Note: if you run mongodb as a non-root user (recommended) you may
# need to create and set permissions for this directory manually,
# e.g., if the parent directory isn't mutable by the mongodb user.
dbpath=/var/lib/mongodb

#where to log
logpath=/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

logappend=true

#port = 27017

# Listen to local interface only. Comment out to listen on all interfaces.
bind_ip = 127.0.0.1

# Disables write-ahead journaling
# nojournal = true

# Enables periodic logging of CPU utilization and I/O wait
#cpu = true

# Turn on/off security.  Off is currently the default
#noauth = true
#auth = true

# Verbose logging output.
#verbose = true

# Inspect all client data for validity on receipt (useful for
# developing drivers)
#objcheck = true

# Enable db quota management
#quota = true

# Set oplogging level where n is
#   0=off (default)
#   1=W
#   2=R
#   3=both
#   7=W+some reads
#diaglog = 0

# Ignore query hints
#nohints = true

# Enable the HTTP interface (Defaults to port 28017).
#httpinterface = true

# Turns off server-side scripting.  This will result in greatly limited
# functionality
#noscripting = true

# Turns off table scans.  Any query that would do a table scan fails.
#notablescan = true

# Disable data file preallocation.
#noprealloc = true

# Specify .ns file size for new databases.
# nssize = <size>

# Replication Options

# in replicated mongo databases, specify the replica set name here
#replSet=setname
# maximum size in megabytes for replication operation log
#oplogSize=1024
# path to a key file storing authentication info for connections
# between replica set members
#keyFile=/path/to/keyfile
```

the container ower set STORAGE_ENGINE in env while the container start running
the enviroment of the container is:

```
# mongod.conf
STORAGE_ENGINE=wiredTiger
HOSTNAME=bb544551ec2b
MONGODB_PASS=xxxxxx
LS_COLORS=
AUTH=yes
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/etc
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
JOURNALING=yes
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
OLDPWD=/
```

the logs under tutum/mongodb:3.0:

[image: the logs under tutum/mongodb:3.0]

Comment: Hi Kevin Wang; images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. Instead of showing a screenshot of your terminal, could you copy and paste or type the relevant information into the post directly? cf http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you performed your backup.

1 - You took a filesystem snapshot.
=> you can untar your snapshot in your data folder (check on mongod.conf where is located your data folder).

2 - You used mongodump command.
=> you need to use mongorestore command

Comment: I did nothing for backup.I just have the database file(some .wt file).I upload a screenshoot about what file I have

Comment: OK so you only have to remove the mongod.lock and copy these data in your data folder (in your new container)

Comment: which file I need to copy?all the file except th mongod.lock or just the .wt file?

Comment: all the files except the mongod.lock

Comment: I tried,but failed.I'll upload the logs Screenshot in my question box

Comment: it is because your old mongo container was running with mmapv1 storage and your new mongo container is running with wiredtiger. You need to change the mongod.conf and set the field storage.engine to mmapv1. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.engine

Comment: when I changed the storageEnginer to mmapv1, it told me  <Cannot start server. Detected data files in /data/db created by storage engine 'wiredTiger'. The configured storage engine is 'mmapv1'., terminating>

Comment: sorry I am tired -_- it is the inverse =>  
it is because your old mongo container was running with wiredtiger storage and your new mongo container is running with mmapv1. You need to change the mongod.conf and set the field storage.engine to wiredtiger.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#storage.engine

Comment: It doesn't seem like this, cause I set STORAGE_ENGINE=wiredTiger.  /cry/cry/cry

Comment: Show me your mongod.conf file please. and which mongo version are your running? From 3.2 it should run by default wiredtiger...

Comment: I update the container mongod.conf and my container enviroment in my question box

Comment: OK. I finally tried to run your docker container. The image tutum/mongodb is a 2.6 mongodb version. Wiredtiger come with 3.0 version.
So I think you are messing here. The mongodb that you remove, what was its image and its version?

Comment: sorry,I was going home now,I will check the version and message you about 1 half hours later.The mongo version is 3.0.4

Comment: OK. So modify your image in your docker-compose.yml file to use image: tutum/mongodb:3.0. Btw, this image is deprecated...

Comment: I used tutum/mongodb:3.0, it was 3.0.4 for mongodb and 2.5.3 for WiredTiger, but I find my lastest update container is 3.0...,so, it's workless also. /cry

Comment: 2.5.3 for WiredTiger is not possible. WiredTiger come from 3.0.0. Please remove your container and recreate it with mongo 3.0 image. Then post the logs here.

Comment: Has been uploaded.I find my question is similar to his.May be I need to modify some file?

Comment: I use the repair_attempt.tgz to modify WiredTiger.turtle and WiredTiger.wt file.then I run commond mongod --dbpath /data/db/ --repair --storageEngine wiredTiger.Unfortunately I got a  Assertion: 28595:-31803: WT_NOTFOUND: item not found  error instead.

Comment: It's really weird to debug as we don't know if you performed a correct backup (but I think you did). I am not sure this error is yours are the same. Do you still have the error when using a new container 3.0 with fresh data ?

Comment: yeah, I tried it on 3.0 and 2.7.5, it's all the same

Comment: Sorry I did not see that you post new logs from 3.0.0. There are the logs before the repair or during the repair?
So you used --repair on /data/db/ but on your conf file, your db path is /var/lib/mongodb. Is it what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

I am struggling with mongodb and the lack of persistent storage across reboots myself. Reading your post here makes me wonder what this means:

From your mongod.conf:

#### Disables write-ahead journaling

#### nojournal = true

and from your environment variable:

#### JOURNALING=yes

Perhaps your env should be:

#### NOJOURNAL=false

or

#### NOJOURNAL=no

(Im also struggling with the markdown here)

I personally was finally able to persist data using this compose section - and by setting an ENV variable NODE_ENV: production (in a different service which was depending on the mongodb service)

```
    image: mongo:4.4
    restart: always
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: something
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: otherthanthis
    volumes:
      - ./mongodata:/data/db:cached
```